# Run app from removable drive without sudo

Tags: google-chrome, portable

I want to run apps like Google Chrome in my lab PC where I don't have administrator access meaning I can't run sudo command to do any thing. Is it possible to make apps run from removable drive like the portable apps in windows? Is there any way of doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe yes, maybe no. Insert the USB key, wait several seconds for it to  be mounted, then type `mount`. It will give you several lines of output, one of which applies to the USB key. On my system (YMMV) this is (for one of my USB keys):

```
/dev/sdb1 on /media/walt/ADATA UFD type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2)
```

You hope for the presence of the `exec` option, and the absence of the `noexec` option.

Read `man 8 mount` to learn what these options mean.

Consider your school's Acceptable Use Policy. Is running programs from personal USB keys allowed? Is your Academic Career at risk if you do this?